# Press Enter Key in qtp

Tags: vbscript, qtp

How to perform the Pressing of Enter Action in QTP. I'm selecting a cell and able to set a value ,now I want to press <kbd>enter</kbd> key and get the list from that Java Edit box. Which are the different ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use mentioned above Type method: `YourObject.Type micReturn`
2. Use SendKeys method:

   Function SendKeys(sKey)

   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   WshShell.AppActivate "Your browser" ' You may need to activate your browser first

   WshShell.SendKeys sKey

   wait(1) ' You may need to add some Wait statements around

   End Function

In your case it will be

```
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

See [MSDN SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) and [MSDN AppActivate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I tried with by using mercury.devicereplay, It didnt worked earlier, That was becous of Constants being defined in the Functions. So only i used Wshell.shell , it worked for me.... Thank  u all...

Comment: @TestGeek, if the answer solved your problem why don't you accept it? (or at least vote it up).

Answer (score 0):

You can either send key (micEnter) through *.Type()* method of the object or use *FireEvent* to invoke an event handler directly.

Answer (score 0):

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.AppActivate

WshShell.SendKeys (ENTER)            '--------parenthesis